# Spark Scala filter on group of result

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, group-by

I am trying to filter a Data Frame on a group of result.

Sample Dataframe code -

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
      (1, 1, "m10", "t22"),
      (1, 2, "m10", "t22"),
      (1, 3, "m11", "t22"),
      (1, 4, "m11", "t22"),
      (1, 5, "m10", "t22"),
      (1, 6, "m10", "t22"),
      (1, 7, "m10", "t22"),
      (1, 8, "m11", "t22"),
      (1, 9, "m10", "t22"),
      (1, 10, "m10", "t22"),
      (2, 1, "m10", "t22"),
      (2, 2, "m11", "t22"),
      (2, 3, "m10", "t22"),
      (2, 4, "m10", "t22"),
      (2, 5, "m10", "t22"),
      (2, 9, "m10", "t22"),
      (2, 10, "m11", "t22"),
      (3, 4, "m10", "t22"),
      (3, 5, "m11", "t22"),
      (3, 6, "m10", "t22"),
      (3, 7, "m10", "t22"),
      (3, 8, "m10", "t22"),
      (3, 9, "m11", "t22"),
      (3, 10, "m10", "t22")
       )
       ).toDF("org_id", "rule_id", "period_id", "base_id")
```

Data looks like below -

```
scala> df.show(50, false)
+------+-------+---------+-------+
|org_id|rule_id|period_id|base_id|
+------+-------+---------+-------+
|1     |1      |m10      |t21    |
|1     |2      |m10      |t22    |
|1     |3      |m11      |t22    |
|1     |4      |m11      |t22    |
|1     |5      |m10      |t23    |
|1     |6      |m10      |t22    |
|1     |7      |m10      |t22    |
|1     |8      |m11      |t22    |
|1     |9      |m10      |t22    |
|1     |10     |m10      |t22    |
|2     |1      |m10      |t22    |
|2     |2      |m11      |t22    |
|2     |3      |m10      |t23    |
|2     |4      |m10      |t22    |
|2     |5      |m10      |t22    |
|2     |9      |m10      |t22    |
|2     |10     |m11      |t22    |
|3     |4      |m10      |t22    |
|3     |5      |m11      |t22    |
|3     |6      |m10      |t22    |
|3     |7      |m10      |t22    |
|3     |8      |m10      |t22    |
|3     |9      |m11      |t22    |
|3     |10     |m10      |t23    |
+------+-------+---------+-------+
```

Based on a properties file, I need to filter the result on group of org_id. properties file looks like -

```
    4=1,2,3
    7=1,4,5
    9=8,10
.....................
.....................
```

In the properties file all the values are rule_id.

I will consider the rows contain rule_id 4 only if any group of org_id contain 1, 2 and 3 rule_ids. Otherwise I need to delete the row contains rule_id 4. Similarly for others rule_id values available in the properties file.

Expected Result -

```
    +------+-------+---------+-------+
    |org_id|rule_id|period_id|base_id|
    +------+-------+---------+-------+
    |1     |1      |m10      |t21    |
    |1     |2      |m10      |t22    |
    |1     |3      |m11      |t22    |
    |1     |4      |m11      |t22    |
    |1     |5      |m10      |t23    |
    |1     |6      |m10      |t22    |
    |1     |7      |m10      |t22    |
    |1     |8      |m11      |t22    |
    |1     |9      |m10      |t22    |
    |1     |10     |m10      |t22    |
    |2     |1      |m10      |t22    |
    |2     |2      |m11      |t22    |
    |2     |3      |m10      |t23    |
    |2     |4      |m10      |t22    |
    |2     |5      |m10      |t22    |
    |2     |10     |m11      |t22    |
    |3     |5      |m11      |t22    |
    |3     |6      |m10      |t22    |
    |3     |8      |m10      |t22    |
    |3     |9      |m11      |t22    |
    |3     |10     |m10      |t23    |
    +------+-------+---------+-------+
```

I am stuck on this and don't know how to proceed on this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved using a SQL window function.

Let's register your original data and the properties file as temporary views `data` and `rule_filters` respectively:

```scala
Seq(
  (1, 1, "m10", "t22"),
  (1, 2, "m10", "t22"),
  (1, 3, "m11", "t22"),
  (1, 4, "m11", "t22"),
  (1, 5, "m10", "t22"),
  (1, 6, "m10", "t22"),
  (1, 7, "m10", "t22"),
  (1, 8, "m11", "t22"),
  (1, 9, "m10", "t22"),
  (1, 10, "m10", "t22"),
  (2, 1, "m10", "t22"),
  (2, 2, "m11", "t22"),
  (2, 3, "m10", "t22"),
  (2, 4, "m10", "t22"),
  (2, 5, "m10", "t22"),
  (2, 9, "m10", "t22"),
  (2, 10, "m11", "t22"),
  (3, 4, "m10", "t22"),
  (3, 5, "m11", "t22"),
  (3, 6, "m10", "t22"),
  (3, 7, "m10", "t22"),
  (3, 8, "m10", "t22"),
  (3, 9, "m11", "t22"),
  (3, 10, "m10", "t22")
).toDF(
  "org_id",
  "rule_id",
  "period_id",
  "base_id"
).createOrReplaceTempView("data")

Seq(
  "4=1,2,3",
  "7=1,4,5",
  "9=8,10"
).map { line =>
  val Array(key, values) = line.split("=")
  (key, values.split(",").map(_.toInt).sorted)
}.toDF(
  "key",
  "rules"
).createOrReplaceTempView("rule_filters")
```

Then the following SQL query solves the problem:

```sql
SELECT
  org_id,
  rule_id,
  period_id,
  base_id
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      array_sort(
        collect_set(rule_id) OVER (
          PARTITION BY org_id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
          AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
        )
      ) AS rules_in_org
    FROM
      data
      LEFT JOIN rule_filters ON rule_id = key
  )
WHERE
  rules IS NULL
  OR array_intersect(rules_in_org, rules) = rules
ORDER BY
  org_id,
  rule_id
```

If you prefer, you may also implement it using the DataFrame API:

```scala
table("data")
  .join(table("rule_filters"), $"data.rule_id" === $"rule_filters.key", "left")
  .select(
    $"*",
    array_sort(
      collect_set($"rule_id").over(
        Window
          .partitionBy($"org_id")
          .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
      )
    ) as "rules_within_org"
  )
  .filter($"rules".isNull || array_intersect($"rules_within_org", $"rules") === $"rules")
  .drop("key", "rules", "rules_within_org")
  .orderBy($"org_id", $"rule_id")
  .show(Int.MaxValue)
```

```
+------+-------+---------+-------+
|org_id|rule_id|period_id|base_id|
+------+-------+---------+-------+
|     1|      1|      m10|    t22|
|     1|      2|      m10|    t22|
|     1|      3|      m11|    t22|
|     1|      4|      m11|    t22|
|     1|      5|      m10|    t22|
|     1|      6|      m10|    t22|
|     1|      7|      m10|    t22|
|     1|      8|      m11|    t22|
|     1|      9|      m10|    t22|
|     1|     10|      m10|    t22|
|     2|      1|      m10|    t22|
|     2|      2|      m11|    t22|
|     2|      3|      m10|    t22|
|     2|      4|      m10|    t22|
|     2|      5|      m10|    t22|
|     2|     10|      m11|    t22|
|     3|      5|      m11|    t22|
|     3|      6|      m10|    t22|
|     3|      8|      m10|    t22|
|     3|      9|      m11|    t22|
|     3|     10|      m10|    t22|
+------+-------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It's working fine. I need one more help. If I want any one rule match condition, instead of all rule match. What should I use. I think array_intersect function will not work in that case.

Comment: @Avijit, you can still use `array_intersect` and just check whether the result is nonempty. Also, in that case, you don't need the extra `array_sort` call anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This approach has multiple joins and aggregations, so hopefully the data is not too big.

Basically, records with sets of rules are created. Then, a join correlates the original records with sub-rules that must exist for that org/rule combination, as well as the rules that are actually exhibited within that org, creating `orgsContainingRulesDF`. Using this DF, you can filter out rules where not all "sub-rules" were exhibited.

```scala
// Assume rule/sub-rule info can be read as either a Map or List of Tuple
val rules = Map(4->Set(1,2,3), 7->Set(1,4,5), 9->Set(8,10))
val rulesDF = rules.toList.toDF("rule", "sub_rules")

// For each org_id, get a set of rules which appear under it
val ruleSetsDF = df.groupBy(col("org_id")).agg(collect_set(col("rule_id")) as "rules")

// For each rule with sub-rules, match with orgs containing that rule
// Also get the full list of rules pertaining to that org
val orgsContainingRulesDF = rulesDF.join(df, $"rule" === $"rule_id", "left").join(ruleSetsDF, Seq("org_id"), "left")

// Create a UDF for determining if all items in first seq are in second seq
val subsetOf = udf((array1: Seq[String], array2: Seq[String]) => {
  Set(array1:_*).subsetOf(Set(array2:_*))
})

// Create DF with items to delete
// i.e. org-and-rule-id-pairs where not all sub-rules appear in exhibited rules
val toDeleteDF = orgsContainingRulesDF.filter(!subsetOf($"sub_rules", $"rules"))

// Use a left anti-join (inverse of left join) to only preserve records
// with no corresponding toDeleteDF record
val resultDF = df.join(toDeleteDF, Seq("org_id", "rule_id"), "left_anti").orderBy($"org_id", $"rule_id")
```

Result is as expected:

```
resultDF.show(25,false)
+------+-------+---------+-------+
|org_id|rule_id|period_id|base_id|
+------+-------+---------+-------+
|1     |1      |m10      |t22    |
|1     |2      |m10      |t22    |
|1     |3      |m11      |t22    |
|1     |4      |m11      |t22    |
|1     |5      |m10      |t22    |
|1     |6      |m10      |t22    |
|1     |7      |m10      |t22    |
|1     |8      |m11      |t22    |
|1     |9      |m10      |t22    |
|1     |10     |m10      |t22    |
|2     |1      |m10      |t22    |
|2     |2      |m11      |t22    |
|2     |3      |m10      |t22    |
|2     |4      |m10      |t22    |
|2     |5      |m10      |t22    |
|2     |10     |m11      |t22    |
|3     |5      |m11      |t22    |
|3     |6      |m10      |t22    |
|3     |8      |m10      |t22    |
|3     |9      |m11      |t22    |
|3     |10     |m10      |t22    |
+------+-------+---------+-------+
```